# Calculate the mean of a function within a part of a circle

Tags: calculus, geometry, definite-integrals, circles

I have a cellular signal calculation function, which calculates the signal given the distance from the antenna. 
Without the constants, the function is basically: 
$f(d)=1/(d^α)$ where $α$ is a parameter.

I need to find the mean of a part of a circle containing points which are the function values.
I will show on an example:

[image: circles cut]

In this picture, assume the center of function $f$ is the center of the **yellow** circle.
Each point inside the green circle has distance $d$ from the center, and a value $f(d)$.

I want to find the mean of the values for all the points in the **green** circle(excluding the blue area, which is determained by the yellow circle!)

I also want to find the mean of the values for all the points in the **blue** circle area, which I assume is done by substracting.

I saw [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/221375/average-value-of-a-complex-valued-function-on-a-circle) that it can be done for a full circle. But how to do it for a part of a circle?

Comment: Does the green circle pass through the center of the yellow circle?

Comment: @Jens Not necessarily. Basically I need to compute the average function value over a part of a circle.

Comment: @Amitai Yuval can you please try to help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $O$ be the center of the yellow disc and $\rho_0$ its radius. Let the blue disc have its center at distance $R$  from $O$, and let $\rho$ be its radius. Consider now concentric circles $\gamma_r$ of variable radius $r$ centered at $O$. For given $r\in[R-\rho,R+\rho]$ find by trigonometric reasoning the angle $2\alpha(r)$ of the arc that the blue disc cuts out from $\gamma_r$. Then the integrals 
$$\int_{R-\rho}^{\rho_0} f(r)\>2\alpha(r)\>r\>dr,\qquad \int_{\rho_0}^{R+\rho} f(r)\>2\alpha(r)\>r\>dr$$
give the "total signal energy" received in the two parts of the blue disc. Divide by the corresponding areas, and you obtain the average signal strengths.

Comment: Thank you!!
How do you explain those results? Are they proven somewhere?

Comment: @BestArmy: The formulas in my answer are "intuitively obvious". For a formal proof you need the formula for variable transformations in multiple integrals.